# How to split value and update query

Tags: java

```
 public static String DuStatusinactiveanddeactive(EmpBean empBeanObj,
                                                ClaimDetailsBean claimDetailsBean,
                                                 HttpServletRequest request) throws SQLException {
        // To get Employee Details from cdm master




        String query = "update GEMS_DELIVERY_UNIT  set isActive=? , TRANS_USER=? where DU_ID=?";
        Connection conn = null;
        conn = DAO.getMsSqlConnection();
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        //System.out.println("came into upgradeClaim"+beanObj.getAppr1Id()+"-->"+beanObj.getAppr2Id()+"-->"+beanObj.getAwaitingAppr()+"-->"+beanObj.getClaimStatus()+"-->"+beanObj.getClaimId());
        try{
             stmt = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(query);
             stmt.setString(1,claimDetailsBean.getDustatus());
             System.out.println("ss"+claimDetailsBean.getDustatus());
             stmt.setString(2,empBeanObj.getEmpId());
              System.out.println("emp"+empBeanObj.getEmpId());

             stmt.setString(3,claimDetailsBean.getDucode());
               System.out.println("ducode"+claimDetailsBean.getDucode());









//where du_id=arr[0];


            System.out.println(query);
            stmt.executeUpdate();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "fail";
        }
        return "Success";





    }
```

now  stmt.setString(3,claimDetailsBean.getDucode()); come to value from action method  value#1 i need split this (value#1) and update query value only. i dont want #1
how to split and update please any one help???

Answer (score 0):

you could simply use split function in java

```
public String[] split(String regex, int limit)
```

or

```
public String[] split(String regex)
```

Comment: stmt.setString(3,claimDetailsBean.getDucode()); this place how to split thats getDucode()?

Comment: String str = claimDetailsBean.getDucode()
    str.split("#")[1] // will give u required string

Comment: String str = claimDetailsBean.getDucode();
               String ss[]=str.split("#");
               
             stmt.setString(3,claimDetailsBean.getDucode());   this right?

Comment: I thin you need 0 index and not 1. Also you need to use ss and not what you have written in last line: stmt.setString(3,claimDetailsBean.getDucode())

Comment: String duCode = claimDetailsBean.getDucode();
              if(duCode != null) duCode.substring(0, duCode.indexOf("#"));
                stmt.setString(3,claimDetailsBean.getDucode());
     i put this coding but not split value

Comment: May I ask to you to vote up or accept the solution if working as desired.

Answer (score 0):

you can use substring

```
claimDetailsBean.getDucode().substring(0, claimDetailsBean.getDucode().indexOf("#"))
```

You can take out claimDetailsBean.getDucode() in separate variable and definitely check for null in case DuCode can be null.

Comment: Hi  Harish i need full coding

Comment: String duCode = claimDetailsBean.getDucode();
     if(duCode != null)
      duCode.substring(0, duCode.indexOf("#"));

Comment: String duCode = claimDetailsBean.getDucode();
     if(duCode != null){
      String value = duCode.substring(0, duCode.indexOf("#"));
      stmt.setString(3,value));
     }